# Clear node-dirty database without IO

Tags: javascript, database, caching, node.js, io

Since the node-dirty database is append-only I tried simply doing `fs.unlinkSync(db_path)` but due to this piece of code being hit too frequently (please do not propose less requests as a solution) I have reason to believe this might be contributing to a serious memory leak basically crashing my server. Is there a way of clearing the node-dirty db without IO?

Comment: Why isn't fewer requests an acceptable solution? Do you have some requirement for a particular number of requests?

Comment: Because that problem indeed will be handled, but later, and the question in itself is still valid. If people who use node-dirty all clear the db using unlink then I will concede. But it seems (ironically) dirty to use IO and I believe there must be other ways.

Comment: How many items are trying to keep track of? When you say 'too frequently', what are the specifics? How many items and how often?

Comment: <1000 items. And I suspect there are "bursts" of requests for deletion (like say 5-50 requests during the period of <10 seconds) but since I deleted synchronously I figured this shouldn't be a problem.